# not able to recover vim encrypted file after :set key=

Tags: vim, encryption

Encrypted a file in vim using `:X`. I opened the file and entered a wrong key, it showed garbage. Then I tried to turn off encryption by executing the following in command mode `:set key=`. Now i'm not able to decrypt the file.

I have encrypted my file so that nobody reads it. If someone try to access the file with wrong key and then execute `:set key=`, then how to get back my original file?

Answer (score 1):

A way to re-try encryption key entry after a wrong attempt is via unloading and re-editing the file:

```
:bdelete | edit #
```

If you have written the (garbled) buffer after `:set key=`, the contents may have been lost, as you have persisted (now unencrypted) the garbage. You can check by attempting a re-edit or looking at the file contents; it should start with `VimCrypt~`.

Comment: Did not find any file with VimCrypt~ after executing :bdelete | edit #